# Check Sharesale affilate link target Url

Tags: php, redirect, http-redirect

I am using Shareasale affiliate API to import the merchant product on my database. I am getting the product Url in this format:

http://www.shareasale.com/m-pr.cfm?merchantID=XXXXX&userID=YYYY&productID=ZZZZ

I am trying to find the target URL where above link redirects. If we check Network tool in Chrome browser, it will first consider as 200 and then 301.

No 301 and 302 redirect checker tool can able to identify the correct URL. I tried these tools:
http://www.redirect-checker.org/
http://www.seoreviewtools.com/redirect-checker-tool/

I am looking for a PHP script that can find the target URL. I already tried a couple of script like following code, but it's not working.

```
$urls = array(
'http://www.apple.com/imac',
'http://www.shareasale.com/m-pr.cfm?
 merchantID=xxxxx&userID=YYYY&productID=zzzzzz'
 );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

foreach($urls as $url) {
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 $out = curl_exec($ch);

// line endings is the wonkiest piece of this whole thing
$out = str_replace("\r", "", $out);

// only look at the headers
$headers_end = strpos($out, "\n\n");
if( $headers_end !== false ) { 
    $out = substr($out, 0, $headers_end);
}   

$headers = explode("\n", $out);
foreach($headers as $header) {
    if( substr($header, 0, 10) == "Location: " ) { 
        $target = substr($header, 10);

        echo "[$url] redirects to [$target]<br>";
        continue 2;
    }   
}   

 echo "[$url] does not redirect<br>";
}
```

It's giving me the following result:

```
 [http://www.apple.com/imac] redirects to [https://www.apple.com/imac]
 [http://www.shareasale.com/m-pr.cfm?merchantID=31933&userID=897279&productID=502320302] does not redirect
```

Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: can you add the php code you have until now and tell what errors you get?

Comment: I just added my code and result.

Comment: Anyone with a suggestion?